# Why does Spring Data MongoDB 1.5.2 fail a with NoSuchMethodError?

Tags: spring, maven, spring-data-mongodb

I can't seem to get the most basic MongoTemplate to initialize with spring-mongodb.

Here's the relevant extract from my POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

My XML context setup looks like this:

```
<mongo:db-factory id="mongoDbFactory"
                  host="${mongo.host}"
                  port="${mongo.port}"
                  dbname="${mongo.db}"/>

<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory"/>
</bean>
```

This results in:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.DefaultMongoTypeMapper
    org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.<init>(MappingMongoConverter.java:104)
    org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.getDefaultMongoConverter(MongoTemplate.java:1670)
    org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.<init>(MongoTemplate.java:205)
    org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.<init>(MongoTemplate.java:191)
...
```

Debugging the initialization of `DefaultMongoTypeMapper` reveals:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.data.util.ClassTypeInformation.from(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/springframework/data/util/TypeInformation;
```

I've tried all sorts of different version combinations for spring-core and spring-data, as well as trying to manually specify a version of spring-data-commons, no dice.

Is there something basic I'm doing wrong here?

EDIT:  Full trace of error is:

```
Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.data.util.ClassTypeInformation.from(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/springframework/data/util/TypeInformation;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1120)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:607)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:598)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:661)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:517)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:458)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:138)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As indicated in the ticket you filed, Spring Data MongoDB 1.5.2 requires Spring Data Commons 1.8.2 (or any other 1.8.x version). The Spring version has to be at least 3.2.10 (although Spring itself doesn't play into the exception you see as it is about a tiny signature change in Spring Data Common's `ClassTypeInformation`). If that's the case, you won't see the original exception.

We generally recommend to use the [Spring Data Releasetrain BOM](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.springframework.data%7Cspring-data-releasetrain%7CDijkstra-SR3%7Cpom) or the [Spring IO platform](http://docs.spring.io/platform/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-using-spring-io-platform-maven) instead of manually dealing with versions.

Comment: Corresponding issue: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-559

Recommendation is to use the Spring IO Platform (http://docs.spring.io/platform/docs/1.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/) which worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try making your dependencies like this ;). You might be missing something from the tutorial page.

```
<dependencies>

    <!-- Spring framework -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- mongodb java driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring data mongodb -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

source: http://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/spring-data-mongodb-hello-world-example/

Comment: Is there a specific reason that it wouldn't work with spring-core 4.0.6 (latest) and spring-mongodb 1.5.2 (also latest)?

Comment: That fails too.  Which makes me wonder if there's something orthogonal to the core config that's interfering

Answer (score 1):

OK.. so it seems there is an incompatibility somewhere.  It's unclear but the stack trace seems to indicate that `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` is trying to call a method of `ClassTypeInformation` that doesn't exist.  This method was last seen in 1.7.3-RELEASE of spring-data-commons.  Reverting to that version appears to fix things, but I'm not sure if this will cause errors elsewhere.

The final POM looks like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I tried in one of my applications: spring-data-commons-1.8.2.RELEASE, spring version is 4.0.6 (spring core, context etc), spring-data-mongodb-1.5.2.RELEASE. This works fine for me.

Comment: @coder Hmmm, ok.  I get further errors possibly related to moving back  to 1.7.3.  When you say, "it works", are you able to instantiate an instance of MongoTemplate?

Answer (score 0):

Try including spring-data-commons Jar. This class is defined here. I guess this is why it is causing the issue.

Comment: The class exists in the classpath, but as you can see from the second error it's trying to execute a method that's not defined.  The class not found error occurs because the containing class could not be initialized