# Unable to create mongotemplate in spring and MongoTemplate

Tags: spring, mongotemplate

ERROR

```
[org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 75) Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongo': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoOptionsFactoryBean] while setting bean property 'mongoOptions'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoOptionsFactoryBean]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: autoConnectRetry
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:282)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:126)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:681)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:624)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:543)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:117)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.init(RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.java:78)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:103)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet$DefaultInstanceStrategy.start(ManagedServlet.java:250)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet.createServlet(ManagedServlet.java:133)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:565)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:536)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.start(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:578)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:100)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:81)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoOptionsFactoryBean]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: autoConnectRetry
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1076)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1021)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:269)
        ... 42 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoOptionsFactoryBean]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: autoConnectRetry
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:164)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1069)
        ... 46 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: autoConnectRetry
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoOptionsFactoryBean.<init>(MongoOptionsFactoryBean.java:44)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:148)
        ... 48 more

    12:11:38,290 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 75) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./BlogServices: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./BlogServices: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongo': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoOptionsFactoryBean] while setting bean property 'mongoOptions'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoOptionsFactoryBean]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: autoConnectRetry
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:84)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongo': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoOptionsFactoryBean] while setting bean property 'mongoOptions'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoOptionsFactoryBean]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: autoConnectRetry
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:282)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:126)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:681)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:624)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:543)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:117)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.init(RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.java:78)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:103)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet$DefaultInstanceStrategy.start(ManagedServlet.java:250)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet.createServlet(ManagedServlet.java:133)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:565)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:536)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.start(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:578)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:100)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:81)
        ... 6 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoOptionsFactoryBean]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: autoConnectRetry
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1076)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1021)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:269)
        ... 42 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoOptionsFactoryBean]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: autoConnectRetry
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:164)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1069)
        ... 46 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: autoConnectRetry
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoOptionsFactoryBean.<init>(MongoOptionsFactoryBean.java:44)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:148)
        ... 48 more

    12:11:38,298 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "BlogServices.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./BlogServices" => "org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongo': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoOptionsFactoryBean] while setting bean property 'mongoOptions'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoOptionsFactoryBean]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: autoConnectRetry
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongo': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoOptionsFactoryBean] while setting bean property 'mongoOptions'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoOptionsFactoryBean]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: autoConnectRetry
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoOptionsFactoryBean]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: autoConnectRetry
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoOptionsFactoryBean]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: autoConnectRetry
        Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: autoConnectRetry"}}
```

**Code/Configuration**

**Applicationcontext.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
        xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.8.xsd">

     <!-- Default bean name is 'mongo' -->
     <mongo:mongo host="localhost" port="27017"/>
      <!-- Default bean name is 'mongo' -->
     <mongo:mongo>
      <mongo:options connections-per-host="100"
       threads-allowed-to-block-for-connection-multiplier="5"
                max-wait-time="120000000"
                connect-timeout="10000000"
                socket-keep-alive="true"
                socket-timeout="15000000"
                auto-connect-retry="true"/>
     </mongo:mongo>
     <!-- Offers convenience methods and automatic mapping between MongoDB JSON documents and your domain classes. -->
       <bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
           <constructor-arg ref="mongo"/>
       <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="mydb"/>
       </bean>

    </beans>`
```

Comment: may be :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25234964/why-does-spring-data-mongodb-1-5-2-fail-a-with-nosuchmethoderror

Comment: @soorapadman  : - I tried to change with schemalocation :  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo.xsd">   .    But this is also not working.  am i not using pom.xml . so i found a problem to find out the dependency.